# Tag cloud (getting data from another database)

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How can I specify database name and path for the xe:dominoViewCloudData control which is a part of Tag cloud control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag cloud control `xe:dominoViewCloudData` can't get data from another database in current version of Extension Library. Reading data from other database is commented out in source code.

Java class com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.tagcloud.ViewTagCloudData (handling xe:dominoViewCloudData):

```
                    // External database access not supported as of 8.5.3!
                    // Core will throw an exception if this case is enabled
                    // Needs a secure and performant means to access external db
//                  case 'd': {
//                      if(key.equals("database")) {
//                          return getDatabase();
//                      }
//                  } break;
```

Config file com.ibm.xsp.extlib.config.raw-extlib-domino-tagcloud.xsp-config:

```
<!-- databaseName property is not supported as of 8.5.3 for security reasons -->
```

Comment: Thank you Knut for a detailed response :-) We found a alternative jquery library we are having to use now because of this issue.